# Bootstrap datepicker: Start picking date from year

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Normally when selecting dates from immediate vicinity of 'today', default behaviour (picking a day of month) works well but when picking birthdays I want the user to start picking the date from years. I looked at the docs but couldn't find any option to do this. I want the datepicker to open with years selection first. As shown in this picture:

[image]

I'm using this plugin: https://bootstrapdatepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Can you be more precise, what datepicker are you using? Is it bootstrap UI datepicker  or some other?

Comment: I'm using this plugin: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `startView` option (0-days, 1-months, 2-years, see plugin docs):

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    startView:2//
});
```